# Windows Identity Foundation: How to delete STS token cookie on server side

Tags: cookies, token, wif

I'm trying to delete WIF STS token cookie on server side, but could not get it to delete. It works only on the client browser side not on the server. I have been searching the web for the last few days but have not found a solution.

**Some of the things i found and tried with no luck are:**
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();              -FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie();           FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CookieHandler.Delete();

var test = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Modules.Get("WSFederationAuthenticationModule") as Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
test.SignOut(true); //throws a null error

The above lines of code get called in my STS web handling the logout. If anyone has any suggestion i would greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using WIF 1.0 (3.5).

Use [WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.wsfederationauthenticationmodule.federatedsignout.aspx).

This sends a wsignout message to the STS, STS deletes cookies, sends wsignoutcleanup to RP, RP deletes cookies.

You are doing a federated sign on so use a federated sign out.

Answer (score 0):

**nzpcmad**- Thanks for responding. I tried your comment and it still did not work for me. My STS server session cookie is still alive.

**As suggested here is what I did in pseudo code:**

1. on my Relying Party on logout method

   public ActionResult Logout()
   {

   ```
   var authModule = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
       WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(new Uri(authModule.Issuer), new Uri(authModule.Realm));

       return null;
   }
   ```

(looks like the method basically sends this message to my sts- "...sso.local.com/?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=http%3a%2f%2fclient1.local.com%2f HTTP/1.1")

2. on my STS (here-sso.local.com)
   I look for the wa=wsignout1.0 and handle my logout with the following

FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut(); FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie(); FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CookieHandler.Delete();

And then do a clean up on the relying party by calling the following uri from within an image-client1.local.com/?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0

Everything works great on the client Browser side. But if i keep a fiddler trace and step into a past request i see that I'm still authenticated inside my STS, which leads me to believe that its because my STS server side auth cookie is still alive.

Do you have any other suggestions or comments? thanks

Comment: So you are using a custom STS? If you navigate to the RP again in the browser after logout do you have to authenticate? Are you sure that the browser isn't logging you again automatically via WIA?

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't answer by creating another question. You should expand the original question and add a comment

Comment: my previous answer was too long for the comment box :) n wanted to get as much info out...
Answer to your questions: 
- Yes, using WIF i put together a web to be my STS (basically to authenticate and issue security token.)  
- if I navigate to the RP after i logout, yes i have to authenticate again.

If I keep Fiddler running in the background, logout of my RP. Go back to Fiddler and replay the http request with Auth Cookie, it passes me back a SAML. if I step into my STS code via VS debugger I'm still authenticated. My expectation- redirected to login page. Not sure what i'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

With the default configuration, WIF will serialize the identity in the cookie and there's no state stored on the server side. This means that you can replay the cookie for as long as the WIF token's lifetime.

You can set WIF (4.5) to use "reference mode", which will instead cache the identity in an in-memory cache and only include a reference in the cookie. With this setup, the cached identity will be cleaned up on the server on logout.

You'll find the details here: http://brockallen.com/2013/02/10/beware-setting-properties-or-registering-events-on-the-sam-and-fam/

In a load balanced scenario, you'd have to implement your own `sessionSecurityTokenCache` against a shared store. Here's a pointer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568669(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: klings I tried your suggestion in WIF 4.5 and it works like a charm. But unfortunately I need a solution for WIF 3.5 and this "isReference" mode property is not available. In my RP running on WIF 3.5 I tried "IsSessionMode" but it doesn't seem to work.
Here is code I added to my Global.asax.cs file in my RP web:
 void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenCreated(object sender, SessionSecurityTokenCreatedEventArgs e)
        {
            FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.IsSessionMode = true;            
        }

Comment: did you got any solution on this other than migrating 4.5